# Got "assertion `function != NULL' failed" while using GLib in Seed

Tags: javascript, gnome, glib

I'm trying to call CLib API from Seed. In JS there is a setTimout API. But not in Seed.
So I use GLib to make a `delay` function:

```
delay = function(time, func) {
  return GLib.timeout_add(time, func);
};
```

It gives error:

```
(seed:26406): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_timeout_add_full: assertion `function != NULL' failed

** (seed:26406): CRITICAL **: Line 9 in w.js: ConversionError Can not convert Javascript value to boolean
```

What is the right way to write it?

Since I didn't found an detailed JS API for Seed. I tried to read the docs for C.
And it looks awful..
http://developer.gnome.org/pygobject/stable/glib-functions.html#function-glib--get-current-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GLib.timeout_add corresponds to [g_timeout_add_full](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add-full).  You're missing an argument (the priority)...  the third argument should be the callback, but since you're not passing anything seed will try to use NULL.

There is an example of using a timeout in Seed in [glib/timeout.js](http://git.gnome.org/browse/seed-examples/tree/glib/timeout.js) in the [seed-examples](http://git.gnome.org/browse/seed-examples/) repository.